# php: how can i add an addition for all values of an imploded array

Tags: php, arrays, addition, implode

Here is my code:

```
$array=array("x1","x2");
$array=implode(" AND ",$array);
echo $array;
```

printing out:

> x1 AND x2

but i want it automatically print for each values of array to:

> x1=x1+y AND x2=x2+y

Comment: `$array[0].=$array[0].'='.$array[0].'+y';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going out on a limb and assuming that it's not just an array of 2 items, and you want to scale this up.  This should work for two items (and more) though.

```
$returnStr = ""; 
$i = 0;
while ($i < count($array)){
    $returnStr .= $array[$i] . "=" . $array[$i] . "+y" . (($i+1 < count($array))?" AND ":"");
    $i++;
}
echo $returnStr;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$array=array("x1","x2");
$array[0]=$array[0].'='.$array[0].'+y';
$array[1]=$array[1].'='.$array[1].'+y';
$array=implode(" AND ",$array);
echo $array;
```

Outputs:
x1=x1+y AND x2=x2+y

Comment: thanks but i wanna automate this for each values. the array can have 1000 values.

Comment: You're welcome. However, you didn't mention that in your original question. @OzzyChigurh see if the other answer given works for you.

Comment: @OzzyChigurh well simply automate `0` and `1` in a loop, would be no hard work

Comment: I've tested `SLoW's` answer, seems to be what you're looking for. @OzzyChigurh